# my bootstrap styles won't render my mobile styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

my bootstrap mobile style won't render unless I add a extra closing brace to the end can someone tell me what I did wrong

this is the styles that I created and they should work but they are not working and they pass the validator test.

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px){

```
.movie{
        width:300px;

        height: 300px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    body > div > div > h3 {
margin-left: 300px;
padding-top: 200px;
}
a:link {
outline: 0;
font-size: 9px;
display: block;
padding-right: 50px;
}
h3{
font-size: 20px;
    margin-top:20%;
}
h3.port {
margin-left: 150px;
color: #9932CC;
margin-top: 50px;
}

img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    margin-top:0;
}

p {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top:5%;
  padding: 0;
  color: #9932CC;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: #9932CC;
     }
body > div > div > a > img {
display: none;
}
.navbar-brand {
float: left;
padding: 10px 15px;
font-size: 20px;
}

     /* twitter
    ====================================== */
    div#iPhone {background: url("../images/iphone.png") no-repeat;
    width:275px;height:500px;
display: inline-block;  
padding-top: 90px;
padding-left:2em;
margin-left: 0px;


}

    iframe#twitter-widget-0.twitter-timeline[style] {width:70px !important;}

    div#iPhone iframe[id^="twitter-widget-0"] {min-width:170px !important;
    margin-right: 20px;
    }
        /* iframe
    ======================================= */
    .movie {
text-align: center;
width: 350px;
height: 345px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 200px;
}
    .paragraph {
width: 50px;
margin-left: 10%;
}
    .thumbnail {

color: #333;
margin-left: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
        border:0px;
}
    .btn-primary {
color: #000;
background-color: #aff6b8;
border-color:black;
    margin-top: 5%;
    width:100%;
}
}
```

}

Comment: if you need to see all the style let me know and i will get them posted

Answer (score 0):

> mobile style won't render unless I add a extra closing brace to the end

Yes, the `@media` syntax involves an extra set of braces:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    element {}
}
```

The last closing brace you added is equivalent to the last one in the code above.

Comment: i had to have three at the end tho to make it work why is that

Comment: Have you run the file through the validator?

Comment: yes and it says without the end curly brace it is right but without it it wont work

Comment: Were there any other errors? Something else is going on, so you'll need to post a link or a demo that shows the problem.